# removing first letters in a string using bash under cgi

Tags: string, bash, cgi

I'm trying to path a web address to a bash script run under cgi. I search a little and found this [link](http://www.team2053.org/docs/bashcgi/gettingstarted.html). From what I understood, this line should separate the variable from it's value:

```
USERNAME=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*username=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"
```

So, reading about sed, I have concluded that this line should be sufficient for my needs:

```
url='echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed "s/url=\(.*\)/\1/"'
```

where the input is

> url=www.web.address.com

However, the variable get is the string is:

> echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed "s/url=(.*)/\1/"
>   if I tried to remove the apostrophes I get an empty variable. Note that if I simply to the `echo` command I the desired effect.

How can I separate the url value?

Comment: You need backticks `\`` (ASCII 96) not regular apostrophes `'`. As an alternative, `url=$(commands ...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parameter expansion and you won't need `sed`.

```
echo "${QUERY_STRING##*=}"
```

To set a variable to that value:

```
url=${QUERY_STRING##*=}
```